# Cocoapods - Is it possible to customise 3rd party iOS libaries?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm writing a project that uses a range of 3rd party iOS libraries (e.g. TWStatus, BSKeyChain), some of which I've modified (up to 10% custom code), but wouldn't be suitable for the original GitHub project.

I thought about future updates from the library authors, and came across [CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods) today, which looks to be a good dependency manager in the same vein as Bundle or Vundle (for Vim).

I'm curious whether it's possible for my custom code to co-exist with future changes by the library authors using CocoaPods??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CoocaPods by default pulls in a library as source, along with instructions to build that library. (There are some exceptions for close-sourced libs). So this makes it easy to debug issues and test changes out within the context of your project.

Having decided on a change, you should do one of the following:

- Submit the change back to the master library. You'll get the benefit of easily being able to upgrade to new versions that include all of the testing provided by the wider community. The easiest way to to do this is to fork the library, apply the change, and send a pull request
- If your changes aren't really of benefit to other users of the library, you can just fork the library, without submitting the change back up to master. If the license permits you can maintain a private fork, and still resolve it from CocoaPods. To do this:

**Podfile:**

```
#As long as the pod-spec is published at the root of the git repo, this works. 
pod 'MyFantasticLib', :git => 'https://github.com/dogue/Doguetastic.git'
#. . and you can use this lib while you're waiting for your pull req. to be approved.
```

You could also consider setting up a [private spec repo](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html).

The first option is usually the best.

Comment: thanks for the explanation @Jasper Blues.  I ended up with a mix - some libraries managed with Cocoapods.  Those that need customisation, I submit a pull request or maintain as my sub-repo if pull rejected :D

Answer (score 2):

So, to be clear.

You've made changes to a dependency 
You also want to keep those dependencies up to date.

--

Seems to me this would be a pain. You'd need to merge the new stuff into your own version for every update, for every pod/dependency.

However, if you've made changes... do you really need to? Consider using the adapter or façade pattern to write a wrapper around them, and then you can update them as much as you like (assuming their interface doesn't change).

Just some thoughts

Comment: +1 for suggesting facade pattern. I was thinking about doing either that or class extension.